# ¿Cómo hago para que si el usuario recarga a página le rediriga a otra?

Tags: javascript

Osea que si el usuario le da a `F5` o a `recargar` le lleve a otra página en vez de recargar.
 Tengo esto.

```js
 <script>
 function Verificar()
{
var tecla=window.event.keyCode;
if (tecla==116) {
 confirm('', function (result) {
     if (result) {
          parent.location=pagina.html;
      } else {
           event.keyCode=0;
event.returnValue=false;
      }
}); 

}
}
 </script>
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto, me sirvio para redirigir

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>


<script>
    document.onkeydown = fkey;
    document.onkeypress = fkey
    document.onkeyup = fkey;

    var wasPressed = false;

    function fkey(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (wasPressed) return;

        if (e.keyCode == 116) {
            window.location.assign("https://www.google.com");
            wasPressed = true;
        }
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Te amo gracias .-

Comment: SI pero si le das a la ruedita no te redirige. Alguién sabe?

Comment: Hola Baker1562, aunque esta respuesta puede ser de ayuda, para que esté completa deberías añadir una explicación de qué es lo que hace y cómo funciona. Lee [answer] para más información.